# Get ERC20-Token Price From Contract

Tags: solidity, web3js

[image]

Contract Address = `0x178Bf8fD04b47D2De3eF3f6b3D112106375ad584`

I am trying to fetch price of this custom token from its contract. If you see the CoinGecko  they are fetching price from contract. How's it possible? please can anyone explain me this. How I can get USD price equivalent from contract?

Answer (score 0):

They are not getting the price from the Token Contract itself but from the contract of the pairs in DEX exchanges.